# g++ -Wsign-compare int vs short

Tags: c++, comparison, unsigned, signed, short

Let's take the following C++ example code:

```
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    unsigned int b = 1;
    if (a < b) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

this is compiled with

```
g++ -Wall -O0
```

and gives the warning

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

as expected.

If I change the types of a and b to short and unsigned short, the compiler warning is gone. Why?

Comment: maybe because they are compared as ints? (by integral promotion)